# Executing external exe in a child window (C++, win32)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have written a simple **win32** program say `abc.exe`.

I have added a button in it, clicking on which an external **exe** say `xyz.exe` should start.

But the original program i.e. `abc.exe` should be inaccessible while `xyz.exe` is running. (Same as in the case of message box where the parent window remains inactive unless message box is closed)

How can Ido it ? 
It would be great if you could post an example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WaitForSingleObject` (IIRC) to wait for the new process to terminate. You can make your window not visible (e.g. via `ShowWindow`) before waiting. Check successful launch first.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed, create the 'xyz.exe' process using `CreateProcess` function and save the new process' handle (`hProcess` in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct you passed in `CreateProcess`).

Then you can disable the 'abc.exe' window by calling `EnableWindow` with `bEnable` set to `FALSE`.
In the window procedure of 'abc.exe', where the `WM_PAINT` message is handled add a check to see if the 'xyz.exe' process is still running. You can do this by using `GetExitCodeProcess` function with the handle you saved earlier and checking if the return value is `STILL_ACTIVE`. If the 'xyz.exe' process is no longer active, you can then enable the 'abc.exe' window using `EnableWindow` again.

Comment: **−1** Checking for `STILL_ACTIVE` exit code in a loop is very dangerous advice: it leads to an infinite loop when the program returns that value, which is just the value 259. It's an indication but not a surefire signal. Instead, for a message loop, you can call `WaitForSingleObject` and pass 0 (zero) for the time-out parameter (and don't do this only on `WM_PAINT`!).

Comment: A better option would be to change your message loop to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` during the time that you are waiting for the external process to exit.  But if that is not an option, using `WM_TIMER` via `SetTimer()` would be more appropriate than using `WM_PAINT` to call `WaitForSingleObject()` periodically.